# Node.js simple While with String.indexOf fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, slice, indexof

I have read a file XML with fs(filesystem) and transformed its Buffer to a simple long String Object, after that I have to search every specific tag combination and add a little text slicing the string, but sometimes fails doing it more than 1 time.

```
 xmldata = /*STRING OBJECT*/
 var index = 0
    while(index != -1) {
        index = xmldata.indexOf("<description>", index + "<description>".length + "/n".length + "<![CDATA[".length)
        var tempIndex = xmldata.indexOf("<div", index + "<description>".length)
        if (index < tempIndex < index + "<description>".length + "/n".length && tempIndex != -1) xmldata = xmldata.splice(tempIndex - 1, 0, "<![CDATA[")
    }

String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
```

a simple entry

```
<description>
<div class='pdbDescContainer'>
```

can become

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<div class='pdbDescContainer'>
```

or like this

```
<description>
<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[<![CDATA[
<div class='pdbDescContainer'>
```

simply I don't know why it does randomly like this

Comment: `index < tempIndex < index` doesn't do what you think it does. It's actually `(index < tempIndex) < index` which, after the first evaluation, you get a *boolean* and compare if it's less than the rest of the expression.

Comment: regex replace ??

Comment: thx VLAZ, I'm too used to program like C and Java, and sometimes I get crazy for simple things thinking that problem is elsewhere, 1 week ago I'm get crazy and after 1 day spent on desk thinking that was a problem of Async and I've discovered that String.replace() just don't modify the string but returns result string modified